# Acquia Dev Desktop 2 extremely slow

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7, acquia

I need help with **Acquia Dev desktop 2**. The **Drupal multisite** on my **localhost** is **extremely slow** and I have searched all over the internet for help on this.

I also tried running **FastCGI** which is the default by it keeps crashing each time i click on a link.

It's running Apache 2, PHP 5.6.

Please see screenshot for the version:

[image: screenshot of version]

Any help to improve the speed will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the computer specs it's running on?

Comment: Windows 7 Premium 64bit

Answer (score 1):

I switch from FastCgi, though it is set as default.

Looks like you are on a Windows machine.

Locate the httpd.conf in C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\apache\conf\httpd.conf

Add the following lines.

```
AcceptFilter https none
AcceptFilter http none
EnableSendfile Off
EnableMMAP off
```

Save and restart on App.

Turning off EnableMMAP, EnableSendfile helped me.

> You can read up on these Apache mods
>   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html

Hope this helps

Comment: these settings did not help me, but I am running on a mac.  Any other suggestions?  a single page load is taking 10+ seconds!